# "Access to path [...] is denied" even when I Run as Administrator

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-8

My program is not liking my `File.Copy`, as it says

> Access to the path 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\Unfriendly\Unfriendly\bin\Debug\Data' is denied

when I try to invoke my function

```
    public void AddFriendList ( string newDataPath )
    {
        // dataPath: Full file path to Facebook data file being added

        string newFriendsPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(new string [] { newDataPath,"html","friends.htm"});

        using ( StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(this._datadir) )
        {
            Match friendsULs = DataReader._lregx.Match(sr.ReadToEnd());
            if ( !friendsULs.Success )
            {
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Couldn't find exactly one piece of HTML matching regex {0}",
                                                    DataReader._lregx.ToString()));                  
            }   

            Dictionary<string, int> friendMap = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            foreach ( Match thisFriendRegex in DataReader._fregx.Matches(friendsULs.ToString()) )
            {
                var thisFriendString = thisFriendRegex.ToString();
                if ( friendMap.ContainsKey(thisFriendString) )
                {
                    ++friendMap[thisFriendString];
                }
                else
                {
                    friendMap[thisFriendString] = 1;
                }

                _fhist.Add(new FriendList { friendNames = friendMap, timestamp = File.GetCreationTime(newFriendsPath) });
            }
        }

        // Copy new data Facebook data into repository
        File.Copy(newDataPath, this._datadir);

    }
```

with `newDataPath` being `C:\Users\Me\Desktop\facebook_data`. I've tried **Run as Administrator** and still get the error.

The full meat of my project can be seen at https://github.com/jamkin/Unfriendly/blob/master/Unfriendly/DataReader.cs and, by the way, it looks like GitHub doesn't know what to do with `@"..."` strings since it's making everything blue after

```
    private static readonly string _instructsBody = String.Format(@"AddFriendList <FacebookDataPath>: Adds to reposistory the instance of Facebook data found at FacebookDataPath\n
                                                                    Example usage: AddFriendList C:\Users\Jamin\Desktop\facebook_data_1\n
                                                                    {0}\n
                                                                    PrintInstructions: Prints instructions (like you just did!)\n
                                                                    {0}\n
                                                                    CompareLastTwo: Shows difference between latest two friends lists in repository",
                                                                    new String('-', DataReader._instructsHeader.Length));
```

Is there a way to write that and not confuse GitHub?

Comment: If `this._datadir` is a directory, then of course this happens if you try to open it as a file in `new StreamReader(this._datadir)`

Comment: @MatthewWatson Can you explain why that is?

Comment: You can't read bytes from a directory as if it were a file.  (What were you expecting to read?  A directory listing?  The contents of the files the directory contains?)